# Conform to a grid relative to another element

Tags: jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

I'm trying to implement a drag-drop grid system that allows users to drag elements from a toolbar and place them in a droppable area that works as a grid. There can be multiple droppable areas in various parts of the page.

If I drag an object onto a Droppable area, is there a way I can make it snap to that object's local grid?

For example:
An icon on the toolbar is at position top: 10; left: 15
A droppable area is at position top: 99; left: 99

If I set the draggable's grid option to [10, 10] it will only move in 10px increments from (10, 15), eg. (100, 95) is valid, but not (99, 99). Ideally I want the draggable's grid movement to offset from the top-left corner of whatever droppable it's inside.

Here is the code I have been trying to use:

```
$(function() {
    $(".draggable").draggable();
    $(".droppable").droppable({
        drop: function(event, ui) {
            ui.draggable.draggable({grid: false});
        },
        over: function(event, ui) {
            ui.draggable.draggable({grid: [20,10]});
        },
        out: function(event, ui) {
            ui.draggable.draggable({grid: false});
        },
        tolerance: "fit"
    })
});
```

This code works alright, but the problem is that regardless of when the grid is turned on, the position that the object was in when it was picked up is used to determine what grid alignment to use:

```
1. Object starts at (0, 0)
2. Pick up, move to (5, 5), enable grid [10, 10]
3. Object aligns to a grid starting at (0, 0).
4. Disable grid, drop object at (7, 7)
5. Pick object up and enable grid [10, 10]
6. object now aligns to grid starting at (7, 7)
```

Is there any way to set a grid-mode draggable's grid offset when it is first dragged into a droppable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution that seems like it will fit my requirements. I added a new div to behave as a marker for the grid position, showing and hiding this div when dragging in and out of the droppable area.

```
$(function() {
    $(".draggable").draggable();
    $(".droppable").droppable({
        drop: function(event, ui) {
            $(".ui-draggable-dragging").show();
            $(this).children(".gridmarker").hide();
        },
        over: function(event, ui) {
            // I hide like this because i'm cloning the draggable
            $(".ui-draggable-dragging").hide();
            $(this).children(".gridmarker").show();
        },
        out: function(event, ui) {
            $(".ui-draggable-dragging").show();
            $(this).children(".gridmarker").hide();
        },
    })
    .append($("<div>").addClass("gridmarker").hide());
```

Then I added a new handler to the body's mousemove event, which moves the gridmarker according to the grid in the droppable area:

```
    $("body").mousemove($.proxy(function(event){
        var leftOffset = event.pageX - $(this).offset().left;
        var topOffset = event.pageY - $(this).offset().top;
        $(this).children(".gridmarker")
            .css("left", leftOffset - leftOffset % 20)
            .css("top", topOffset - topOffset % 10);
    }, $(".droppable")));
});
```